# Jenkins fails to start up and empty plugins directory

Tags: java, jenkins, plugins, centos

I am new to jenkins, I upgraded a couple of plugins(don't remember which), after that I when I try `java -jar jenkins.war`  I end up getting the following error.

```
jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onTaskFailed
SEVERE: Failed Loading global config
java.io.IOException: Unable to read /home/.jenkins/config.xml
```

I went through several links which address this issue, but no luck yet. In this link which I found https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=764711 it says some plugins are missing, and surprisingly, my `/home/.jenkins/plugins/` is empty!!!

How do I restore the necessary plugins from my command line?

I am using `CentOS release 6.8 (Final)`

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered this issue somedays back,however after restarting jenkins service solved the issue. 
The best you can do now is rename your config file. This way jenkins will load with the default startup.